# Flask-login template not rendering static image file (302 Not Found)

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, flask-login

I have created a multi-page dashboard using plotly dash. I am using flask and flask-login to password protect it. Everything is working fine **except** I cannot get the flask template login page to show an image file stored in the /static directory. My browser inspector (chrome) shows a '302 Found' error message in 'Headers', a 'Failed to load response data: No content available because this request was redirected' error message in 'Response' and , and the 'request initiator chain' looks like this:

[image: picture of Request initiator chain]

My current code:

```
server = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static")
load_dotenv()

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
server.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///" + os.path.join(basedir, "users.db")
server.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
server.config.update(SECRET_KEY=os.getenv("SECRET_KEY"))

bcrypt = Bcrypt()

db = SQLAlchemy(server)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(server)
login_manager.login_view = "/login"

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True)

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return db.session.get(User, int(id))

@server.before_request
def check_login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        if request.path in ["/login"]:
            return
        if current_user:
            if current_user.is_authenticated:
                return
            else:
                for pg in dash.page_registry:
                    if request.path == dash.page_registry[pg]["path"]:
                        session["url"] = request.url
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    else:
        if current_user:
            if request.path == "/login" or current_user.is_authenticated:
                return
        return jsonify({"status": "401", "statusText": "unauthorized access"})

message = "Invalid username and/or password."

@server.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == "GET":
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect("/")

        return render_template("login.html", message=message)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.form:
            user = request.form["username"]
            password = request.form["password"]

            user_data = User.query.filter_by(username=user).first()

            if user_data:
                if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user_data.password, password):

                    login_user(user_data)

                    if "url" in session:
                        if session["url"]:
                            url = session["url"]
                            session["url"] = None
                            return redirect(url)
                    return redirect("/")

    return redirect(url_for("login", error=1))

@server.route("/logout", methods=["GET"])
def logout():
    if current_user:
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            logout_user()
    return render_template("login.html", message="You have been logged out.")
```

Not sure if I need to post the entire login.html file, but the code I am using to display the image is:

```
<header>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.jpg') }}"/>
    </div>
</header>
```

I've scoured Stack for the answer and have tried any number of things, but no dice. I am a relative novice with flask and flask-login and so I suspect it has something to do with the code re-routing the static request to /login, but I'm not sure. Any suggestions would be appreciated.